# initializing array with ZeroMemory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

char cMsg[128][12];

is the same this:

```
ZeroMemory(cMsg, sizeof(cMsg));
```

than this?

```
for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    ZeroMemory(cMsh[i], sizeof(cMsg[i]))
```

compilers gives no error with both ways, but are they metods for same objective?

Answer (score 5):

The behavior is going to be the same for `char` arrays, because they have no alignment requirements or padding bytes in the middle. The first way of doing it may be a little faster than the second one, because it uses fewer function calls, the speed-up would be too small to measure reliably on modern hardware, and the net result is going to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

`ZeroMemory` zeroes a block of memory, and arrays are contiguous.

So, zeroing out the entire block in "chunks" rather than all in one go is functionally the same.